# Checking the presence of nodes of one graph in an other graph

Tags: neo4j

I have two graphs and I want to check for each node of the first one, if it exists in second one. I did the following:

```
match (G1:FirstGraph) 
match (G2:SecondGraph)
where    Exists(G2.Name) and G1.Name=G2.Name return G1.Name, Exists(G2.Name) as Is_Present_In_SecondGraph.
```

The problem is that the query return only the nodes which exist in both of the two graphs. this is done by the condition `G1.Name=G2.Name`.
Can someone help me to get for each node its presence verification in second graph?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
MATCH (G1:FirstGraph) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (G2:SecondGraph)
WHERE G2.Name IS NOT NULL AND G1.Name=G2.Name
RETURN G1.Name, G2.Name IS NOT NULL as Is_Present_In_SecondGraph
```

If that doesn't work it could be because you're referencing `G2` in the `WHERE` for the second `MATCH` clause, so you could do this:

```
MATCH (G1:FirstGraph)
WITH G1
OPTIONAL MATCH (G2:SecondGraph)
WHERE G2.Name IS NOT NULL AND G1.Name=G2.Name
RETURN G1.Name, G2.Name IS NOT NULL as Is_Present_In_SecondGraph
```